# nbconvert multiindex dataframes to latex

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to export a multi-index Pandas DataFrame to latex using ipython's nbconvert
but the multi-index rows come out all wrong.
I'm using the following code at the beginning of the code to convert to latex properly (I found it somewhere on SO but can't remember where):

```
from sympy import latex
from IPython.display import HTML, Latex, display, Math
pd.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', True)
def _repr_latex_(self):
    return "\\begin{center} %s \end{center}" % self.to_latex()
pd.DataFrame._repr_latex_ = _repr_latex_  # monkey patch pandas DataFrame
```

the groupby code is pretty large but I have tested it also with smaller codes like:

```
a = np.array([[1, 3, 4, 5],
             [1, 5, 36, 2],
             [3, 6, 23, 5],
             [2, 2, 1, 6],
             [2, 5, 1, 99]])
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['A','B','C','D'])
df.groupby(by=['A','D']).sum()
```

The result of this is

```
    \begin{center} \begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
{} &  B &   C \\
A D  &    &     \\
\midrule
1 2  &  5 &  36 \\
  5  &  3 &   4 \\
2 6  &  2 &   1 \\
  99 &  5 &   1 \\
3 5  &  6 &  23 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 \end{center}
```

This example shows only the first of the problems, this output will show the multiindex stacked one on top of the other, but I can't find a way of formatting it before output. (I am producing many large tables of this sort so formating on latex itself would [and is] a pain). also with a couple of multi-index more, it gets totally unreadable. The second big problem is that Ipython renders this tables with display() really nicely adjusting column width to screen, but on latex it exceeds the page width and most of the table is lost.

I have searched all over for a better formating solution for nbconvert but couldn't find a thing. Please if you have had this problem also or you know a solution to any of this two problems please tell me.

pd: I'm using python 2.7.7 Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit) and the latest versions of pandas(0.14.1) and ipython(2.2.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug in `to_latex`, and the result of `res.T.to_latex()` doesn't look right either.

A workaround might be to modify the index:

```
In [11]: res = df.groupby(by=['A','D']).sum()

In [12]: res.index = res.index.map(lambda x: ' & '.join(map(str, x)))

In [13]: res.index.name = 'A & D'

In [14]: res.columns.values[0] = ' & ' + res.columns[0]

In [15]: print res.to_latex(escape=False)  # the whole point is not to escape the &s
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
{} &   & B &   C \\
\midrule
A & D  &       &     \\
1 & 2  &     5 &  36 \\
1 & 5  &     3 &   4 \\
2 & 6  &     2 &   1 \\
2 & 99 &     5 &   1 \\
3 & 5  &     6 &  23 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: There's a merged PR about the column-wise behaviour (now fixed), and I think the index part will also be fixed in 0.15. https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7982

Comment: would `df.reset_index().to_latex(index=False)` also be a reasonable work-around?

Comment: @PaulH certainly an easier one! :) I guess the issue is whether it being a MI has any value in the repr.

Comment: Agreed -- In a notebook, I find it crucial to distinguish row labels from column values. Once it goes into a report, I doubt the reader cares. Hence the work-around I've been using for some time now.

Comment: awesome guys, thanks for the answer! just btw, is the "monkey patch" I posted the only way to make the notebook convert properly to latex or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: @BenjaminVatter Yes to monkey patching! Also there's a bug here {lrr} should be replaced to {llrr}. Note: I submitted [patch](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8219) to fix this, hopefully will make it in 0.15.

Comment: Thanks Andy! I will try to make a patch for the multirow issue when I have the time. In the to_excel, its really well formatted and it would be nice to have an export to latex working as fine as that one.

Comment: @BenjaminVatter I think the multirow (MultiIndex column) issue might already be fixed in master!

Comment: @PaulH I put a PR together to fix, would be great if you could take a look/comment (basically I am unsure about the `{}`, but seems to work!) https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8219, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Strange. I tried something similar with .to_html () tonight, only to find that the output displayed the html rather than rendering it. It looks to me very similar to your result.

FWIW. Using IPython 2.2, on a Mac, with anaconda modules.

Comment: yeah that's pretty normal. If you are using Ipython notebook, when using display() the default call is to to_html() if i'm not mistaken and then it renders it. I think most of the to_something are meant to be used for file export. Anyway that was not the problem in this case, but rather the way it was structuring the data in to this new representation.